# What is the industry-preferred way to implement a long-running, constantly monitoring task in Android?

Tags: android

Like the title says, what is the industry-preferred way to implement a long-running, constantly monitoring task in Android?

For example, there is a way to obtain the cell signal strength:

```
public void getData(){
    int cellSignalStrength = 0;
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    List<CellInfo> cellInfos = telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo();
    for(CellInfo info : cellInfos){
        if(info instanceof CellInfoCdma){
            cellSignalStrength = ((CellInfoCdma) info).getCellSignalStrength().getLevel();
        } else if(info instanceof CellInfoGsm){
            cellSignalStrength = ((CellInfoGsm) info).getCellSignalStrength().getLevel();
        } else if(info instanceof CellInfoLte){
            cellSignalStrength = ((CellInfoLte) info).getCellSignalStrength().getLevel();
        } else if(info instanceof CellInfoWcdma){
            cellSignalStrength = ((CellInfoWcdma) info).getCellSignalStrength().getLevel();
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, I would like to monitor this constantly. Is using a `Timer` with `TimerTask` the "best", industry-preferred way to constantly monitor this?

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        getData();
    }
}, 100);
```

Or, is there some other, better way to do this, like a `while(true)` loop inside of an Android Service?

Thanks!

Comment: Please define what "constantly" means in this context. Do you mean "constantly while my activity that needs this data is in the foreground"?

Comment: Yes, while the activity is in the foreground. My apologies for leaving that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a bit on your planned use for the data.

If your primary, if not sole, use case for the data is to update your UI, and the work itself is cheap (<1ms to process), the cheapest thing to use is `postDelayed()`:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  Covered in detail in the book _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.post;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PostDelayedDemo extends Activity implements Runnable {
  private static final int PERIOD=5000;
  private View root=null;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    root=findViewById(android.R.id.content);
  }

  @Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    run();
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
    root.removeCallbacks(this);

    super.onStop();
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(PostDelayedDemo.this, "Who-hoo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
         .show();
    root.postDelayed(this, PERIOD);
  }
}
```

Here, I am simply showing a `Toast` every five seconds, but you can update the period and the work in the `Runnable` to do what you need.

Using `postDelayed()` avoids creating any background threads and having to deal with inter-thread communication back to the main application thread to get your UI updated.

If your work is going to be more expensive (e.g., disk I/O, network I/O), you could use `TimerTask`, though I prefer `ScheduledExecutorService` (added to Java around 1.4, more flexible).

You should not need an Android service, though, if you only need this processing to go on while your activity is in the foreground. Services are for when you have work that needs to be done even if the user leaves your UI and heads off to some other app.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll look into both of these options.